# CSS Create a transparent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, transparency, transparent

Is there a way to make a div HTML element half transparent?

Comment: One downside to translucent containers - all contents of the div, like text, images, etc, will also be translucent.  I recommend you position another container on top of this one with any contents inside.  Of course, if you're not putting anything inside the div, then you're good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a background PNG file which is half transparent, and hoping you don't have to support IE6?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Would the background image be used as the background for the div, or would it be placed on top of the div somehow?

Answer (score 12):

With CSS, this is cross browser solution

```
div {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0.5);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
}
```

NOTE: Right now in every browser, you only need `opacity` see [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/css-opacity). It works even in IE9.

Comment: Better than my idea, by much.

Answer (score 8):

This will work with every browser

```
div {
 -khtml-opacity:.50; 
 -moz-opacity:.50; 
 -ms-filter:”alpha(opacity=50)”;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity:.50; 
}
```

If you don't want transparency to affect the entire container and it's children, check this workaround http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

Comment: Actually I found out that indeed, the whole content gets transparent, while I want only the background to be transparent. I have markup like:
<ul class="level2">
<li><a class="level2" href="SearchResults.aspx?c=9">text</a></li>
<li><a class="level2" href="SearchResults.aspx?c=10">text</a></li>
<li><a class="level2" href="SearchResults.aspx?c=11">text</a></li>
</ul>
Is there a way to make the text not transparent? The referenced article contains absolute positioning and uses sibling containers, but I can't change the hypertext markup.

Comment: Using Relative Positioning for the inside container and Absolute positioning for the outside container as suggested in the i provided is the only way you can do transparent background without affecting the inside text, otherwise you'll need to use a transparent image instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the **background** of your div semi-transparent, not any text and elements inside it, you can simply set a background-color to a transparent-one (i.e. with alpha < 1).

One example is at [our website](http://www.fencing-game.de/en/origin.html), a minimized example here:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Transparency test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-image: url(http://www.fencing-game.de/style/background6.png);
    }
    #trans {
      background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
      max-width: 80ex;
    }
    p {
    max-width: 70ex;
    margin: auto;
    }
    #nontrans {
      background-color: rgb(255,255, 0);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="trans">
    <p>normal text</p>
    <p id="nontrans">nontransparent</p>
    <p>normal text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that this technique doesn't work for IE6, IE7 and IE8. Here's a hack for that: http://dimox.net/cross-browser-rgba-support/